# Unable to set refresh rate to 75 Hz, stuck at 60 Hz

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, refresh-rate

I have an end user whose eyes are sensitive to screen flicker and requires a setup with a refresh rate higher than 60 Hz, set to 75 Hz.

I have an HP Compaq Pro 6300 with an NVidia GeForce 210 graphics card and HP LE2202x monitor. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit. The monitor settings won't allow me the option to raise the refresh rate higher than 60 Hz, even though the technical specifications for my hardware allow me to configure it at a much higher rate. I'm using a single monitor setup running the latest video drivers. I'm plugged into the monitor using an analog (VGA) cable and the screen resolution is set to 1280 x 800. I understand that typically the lower resolutions allow for higher refresh rates. Lowering it doesn't seem to give me options higher than 60 Hz.

Now that I've provided the technical details, any ideas why I'm unable to set the refresh rate higher than 60 Hz?

Comment: Are you trying to change the refresh rate on the monitor itself on in the graphics card driver software?

You could try setting the refresh rate in the "Desktop > (right click) > Screen Resolution > Advanced Settings... > Monitor". This might let you change the Refresh rate.

Comment: Datasheet of monitor, if anyone is interested: http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/LE2202x_data_sheet_050611.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the contrast to old  CRT display, new LCD displays work different. They do not flicker as a CRT display. The common refresh rate for LCD displays is 60 Hz, although I've seen LCD displays with higher refresh rates like 70 Hz. Even sensitive user won't need any higher refresh rate on a LCD display.

Please look into the datasheet of the monitor HP LE2202x. It's "native resolution" and also the supported resolutions are given for 60 Hz. Therefore the driver won't let you overclock the frequency.

Comment: Data sheet is here: http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/LE2202x_data_sheet_050611.pdf

Comment: I appreciate the information. The data sheet was helpful. I should have researched that before submitting my question.